# what parenthesis mean in this context?

Tags: go

In some source code I found this :

```
if etherbase != (common.Address{}) {
    return etherbase, nil
}
```

`etherbase` is of type `common.Address` and it is defined as this:

```
// Lengths of hashes and addresses in bytes.
const (
    HashLength    = 32
    AddressLength = 20
)
// Address represents the 20 byte address of an Ethereum account.
type Address [AddressLength]byte
```

The question is: what do parethesis mean in this context? Why can't they be omitted? Like this:

```
if etherbase != common.Address{} {
    return etherbase, nil
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)
>
> A parsing ambiguity arises when a composite literal using the TypeName
>   form of the LiteralType appears as an operand between the keyword and
>   the opening brace of the block of an "if", "for", or "switch"
>   statement, and the composite literal is not enclosed in parentheses,
>   square brackets, or curly braces. In this rare case, the opening brace
>   of the literal is erroneously parsed as the one introducing the block
>   of statements. To resolve the ambiguity, the composite literal must
>   appear within parentheses.
>
> ```
> if x == (T{a,b,c}[i]) { … }
> if (x == T{a,b,c}[i]) { … }
> ```

---

An ambiguous composite literal `common.Address{}` before an `if` block `{ … }`.

```
if etherbase != common.Address{} {
    return etherbase, nil
}
```

An unambiguous composite literal `(common.Address{})` before an `if` block { … }.

```
if etherbase != (common.Address{}) {
    return etherbase, nil
}
```

---

For example,

```
package main

const AddressLength = 20

type Address [AddressLength]byte

func f(etherbase Address) (Address, error) {
    // Unambiguous
    if etherbase != (Address{}) {
        return etherbase, nil
    }
    return Address{}, nil
}

func g(etherbase Address) (Address, error) {
    // Ambiguous
    if etherbase != Address{} {
        return etherbase, nil
    }
    return Address{}, nil
}

func main() {}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/G5-40eONgmD